# Choosing VS2008 .Net 3.5 and .Net 3.5SP1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

here is the problem. I have one PC using VS2008 (SP1 ) and another PC using VS2008(normal). I want my .Net projects to be editable in both these PC's. So naturally my projects use .Net 3.5 by default and not .Net 3.5 SP1.

So, Is there a way I can fix my VS2008 (SP1) version to stick to .Net 3.5 and not .Net 3.5 SP1. In project properties->Application->TargetFramework I dont see an option for .Net 3.5 SP1.

(Note: I know that there are solution like uninstalling SP1 or Installing SP1 on the other PC. I am asking is there any other way)

Comment: What's your reason to run the pre-SP version? Do you _like_ bugs?

Comment: (@John Saunders) - :) I am not the only one running pre-SP version. I have my reasons. and is there any specific bug you would like to share?

Comment: First, VS will not differentiate service packs of the framework. Second, here's a list of items fixed by SP1: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950263/. You say you have your reasons. I would be interested in knowing your reasons for avoiding VS 2008 SP1.

Comment: @Thomas. the reason?...I don't have control over the other PC.

Comment: @SysAdmin: many of us have to work with stupid people. It's unnecessary to enable them.

Comment: @SysAdmin - LOL. The most obvious reason did not occur to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service packs are combination of various new features , fixes for some knows issues , performance improvement etc.Service packs are closely coupled with the original product for which they are actually targeted. It would make more sense to provide SP1 for the other machine(SP are actually free downloads).Service packs cannot stand as an all alone entity and thus cannot be featured as target framework.Its the service pack(SP1) of VS 2008 that adds the real meat to the original product.It adds loads of new feature to the original product ie VS 2008.